# Join multiple tables even if column value is null

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table `Users`, which has foreign keys to 3 other tables (table has 10 other columns, but are not relevant)

```
ID    CityId    CountryID    StateId
1     1         2            null
2     4         2            null
3     54        3            1
```

Now i need to join City, Country and State tables on their respected `ids`. All 3 tables follow this pattern bellow `[ID/Name/Language/ColumnNameID]`

City table:

```
ID   Name       CityId  Language
1    Budapest   1       En
2    Paris      15      En
3    Berlin     54      En
4    Szeged     4       En
```

Country table:

```
ID   Name      CountryId  Language
1    Hungary   2          En
2    Germany   3          En
```

State table:

```
ID   Name      StateId    Language
1    Berlin    1          En
```

And here's the query, for `leftJoin`-ing all three tables to the Users table:

```
$results = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('city', 'users.city_id', '=', 'city.city_id')
    ->where('city.language', '=', 'en')
    ->leftJoin('country', 'users.country_id', '=', 'country.country_id')
    ->where('country.language', '=', 'en')
    ->leftJoin('state', 'users.state_id', '=', 'state.state_id')
    ->where('state.language', '=', 'en')
    ->select('country.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'country.name as country_name', 'city.name as city_name', 'state.name as state_name')
    ->get();
```

Works, but I do not get the results where in the `users` table under the `state id` column the values are `null`. Here's how it looks like:

```
Id  First_Name    Last_Name  City_Name   Country_Name  State_Name
2   XXX           XXX        Berlin      Germany       Berlin
```

The two entries which have StateID = null are missing. Anything i can do about that?

Comment: Move the condition from WHERE to ON (to the condition for LEFT JOIN). In SQL this looks like `FROM users LEFT JOIN city ON (users.city_id = city.city_id AND city.language = 'en') LEFT JOIN country ...`.

Answer (score -1):

The `where('state.language', '=', 'en')` is dropping the rows where the state id is null.   You have to add a condition that the language could be null if you want to keep those rows.  I'm not sure how you would implement that in Laravel but the SQL would be like:

```
where (state.language is null or state.language = 'EN')
```